# Show XML string in html SPAN tag

Tags: xml, html

I have some string values in a dataset. In my composite control, in RenderContent I add dataset values to html table cells using span tags. It works great until I have an xml string in my dataset.

In my RenderControl I have code something like:

```
output.Write(@"<span id=""valueSpan{0}"" action=""edit"" type=""text"">{1}</span>", this.ID + row["ID"], row["Value"]);
```

row["Value"] contains string value of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><testdata>need to display this xml string in span</testdata>
```

The result I see is "need to display this xml string in span" not the XML data as "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><testdata>need to display this xml string in span</testdata>`". I think I need to let html know that this is just a value. But how???

Comment: I think putting the value of the row["Value"] inside the <span>"here"</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `<` and `>` characters, transforming them to their corresponding character entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Use [Server.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) to do this for you:

```
output.Write(
   @"<span id=""valueSpan{0}{1}"" action=""edit"" type=""text"">{2}</span>",
   this.ID, row["ID"], Server.HtmlEncode(row["Value"].ToString())
);
```

(Also, note that I removed the concatenation `this.ID + row["ID"]` in favor of a string.Format() style syntax.)

Comment: Thanks Humberto! It was difficult to find who answered first as it shows answered 1 hour ago for all :) but then I hovered over that text to get he actual time ;) you got it one minute before others :). Thanks for the suggestion as well. I used System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(row["Value"].ToString())

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using C#.
I think you should use HtmlEncode to encode the XML data so you are able to show it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: Can I use it in my CompositeControl class? I am asking this because I don't see Server.HtmlEncode although I have System.Web added to my project. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Never mind, got the soultion. I tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the <> characters before you add them to the string. (the escape codes are < and >